# Large matrixes in Java

Tags: java, python, matrix, out-of-memory

I have a big matrix (around 100x20.000.000) integer elements. I am storing this as an ArrayList of Lists. Unfortunately Java does not like that and I get an OutOfMemoryError.

Is there a good way to store a big matrix in Java?

I am used to pythons "import library to do this for you". Is there a suitable library for this in java?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711656/java-large-datastructure-for-storing-a-matrix) is not a solution of my problem, because in that post the user tried to store strings. The solution was to map the strings to integers and thus save some space. I can not do that. I just have a big matrix of ints.

Comment: Are You using all values of this matrix? If yes, You need at least 4x50M=200MB of RAM just to store raw matrix data. It is not that much. I think simply setting java runtime param e.g. -Xmx2040m should fix OutOfMemoryError

Comment: @zolv Thank you for that, I will try that.

Comment: @csmckelvey So the suggestion from that post is to just use an array instead of a list? I think the hash map is not feasible for me, because the is no restriction on the range, meaning the content can be any random integer

Comment: @csmckelvey I will look into your post again. Maybe it solves it

Comment: An `int` uses 4 bytes, but an `Integer` and reference uses around 32 bytes each. If you are having trouble with memory use an `int[]` instead of a `List<Integer>`

Comment: If the array is mostly zeroes, a sparse array based on a map is a good idea.  If it's mostly integers -- especially integers with high magnitude -- an `int[][]` will be more efficient than a `List<List<...>>`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I tried to go with `int[]`. It still did not work.

Comment: @User12547645 can you show an example of this not working as it works for me. This suggests you are doing something else which is causing the problem.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Is there only the android implementation of the SparseArray or is there also a different one? Any native support for these things in java?

Comment: A straight `HashMap` doesn't do a bad job on that metric.  There's nothing better built in.

Comment: @User12547645 an `int[]` is native support in Java, what do you mean?

Comment: Sanity check: how much RAM do you have, anyway? With no overhead and no compression, storing this data would consume 8 GB of storage on its own, and that's before you try to do any actual operations on it.

Comment: @user2357112 Around 8GB... Is it possible to store this in a sparse matrix? Sorry, again for the confusion here. I am used to python where this is really no problem at all

Comment: @User12547645: This would be just as much of a problem in Python. Python and Java are both limited by your available memory.

Comment: The matrix should be sparse, so I can just use some implementation of a sparse matrix in python. This seems to be a problem in java, because that seems not to be supported by the language nativly

Comment: @User12547645: Python doesn't have native sparse matrices either. You need a library for those, like SciPy. You can find a library with sparse matrix support in Java, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just have a big matrix of ints.

So use a big matrix of `int`

```
int[][] ints = new int[100][500_000]; // uses about 200 MB each.
```

If you have `List<List<Integer>>` each one will use about 8x as much.

I ran the following with `-Xmx300m` which is 1/7 the heap size you are using.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[][] ints = new int[100][500_000];
    for (int[] arr : ints) {
        Arrays.fill(arr, 1);
    }
}
```

This runs without error.

---

If the martix is very sparse, using `Maps` can help. I suggest using a wrapper class like this.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SparseMatrix<T> {
    final Map<Integer, T>[] maps;
    final int rows, columns;

    public SparseMatrix(int rows, int columns) {
        maps = new Map[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            maps[i] = new HashMap<>();
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public int getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public T get(int r, int c) {
        return maps[r].get(c);
    }

    public void set(int r, int c, T t) {
        maps[r].put(c, t);
    }
}
```

For more fully features library google suggests https://java-matrix.org/ which has a comparison of many matrix libraries in Java.

Comment: I am sorry, I was wrong. I is not 500k it is around 20.000.000 per row...

Comment: @User12547645 the matrix must be very sparse, what percentage of values are actually set?

Comment: Not very much. Is there a good implementation of a sparse array in java? Maybe not the android one but a "native" solution by any chance?

Comment: @User12547645 a sparse matrix only helps if your matrix is very sparse, as it approaches more than about 10-50% full depending on the implementation, it starts to get larger than not using a sparse matrix at all. btw 100x20M works with 8 GB of memory.

Comment: @User12547645 another option is a matrix which is full but highly compressable. What works best entirely depends on what data you have.

Comment: A map can act a lot as a sparse vector, but the syntax in Java would be miserable.  You could try groovy--a groovy file can just be dropped into a java project and interact with Java just like any java class but it's array syntax is actually implemented as a map (sparse).  The syntax is nearly 100% java compatible as well, and I believe groovy's speed these days approaches java if you use the indy build.

Comment: @BillK The OP has stated that the matrix is "not very much" sparse so a Map could end up being much larger.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read that as "Not very much" values are actually set in the array :)

Comment: @BillK in that case, a `Map` is a good choice. Not hard to write a sparse Matrix class.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Not at all difficult but the syntax to access it is miserable in Java, I did it once.  I love java but pure math is not it's forte'  In particular when I started trying to implement abstract matrices that could use different (integer, float) implementations.  A big part of the problem was that the base class for numbers doesn't have any operations in it.  Groovy just fluffs up the Java syntax to be able to look more math-like for those who want to emphasize the expression of math over code.